# Is it possible to select a ViewObject in TableViewCell Content

Tags: ios, uitableview

In other places, we can drag the object as `Outlet` in a ViewController, give it a `name` and use it as a reference later. But, In a table cell is it possible to select the Object through Code as:

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("menuCell") as UITableViewCell

let contentView:UIView = cell.contentView;

//Can we achieve this?
let imgView = contentView.ImageView
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Even though the subviews are added to the contentView, the outlets should be made to the cell itself. So you should have outlets in your cell's .h file, and connect them from the cell to the subview in IB. In code, you would refer to them with cell.label, etc.

Comment: I am using Swift. And I don't have a seperate Class for Cells.

Comment: You need to create your own subclass of UITableViewCell if you want to do any customization. It's easy to do.

Comment: @user2078462, so what are you trying to do with contentView.ImageView? What is that? I see in your code you're already accessing the imageView with cell.imageView, which is the correct way to do it.